# Paths.get - specify a platform?

Tags: java, scala, path

I am working on an application that is being developed on both Mac and Windows. We are generating some file paths and want the paths generated to all be in the UNIX flavor with forward slashes. Calling `Paths.get(...)` on the Windows machine produces paths with the backslashes, but I want it to produce paths with forward slashes.

I couldn't find documentation about "setting" or specifying the path separator to be used.

Comment: Why? `Paths` is doing the correct job based on the platform

Comment: We generate this path to fetch data from a remote server. They specify that the path given must be in UNIX form.

Comment: Then I would suggest running the `String` result through `replaceAll`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried to find it some time ago too but it's impossible. It's static method in `Paths.get(...)`

```
java.nio.file.FileSystems#getDefault
```

which returns the static final field

```
static final FileSystem defaultFileSystem = defaultFileSystem();
```

and `java.nio.file.FileSystems.DefaultFileSystemHolder#defaultFileSystem` detects your filesystem.

But in the instance of `FileSystem` the type of slash is hardcoded: 
https://github.com/frohoff/jdk8u-jdk/blob/master/src/windows/classes/sun/nio/fs/WindowsFileSystem.java#L249

So i think the simplest way for you is to use something like https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringJoiner.html

Comment: Thanks! I suspected it wasn't possible. We'll find an alternative, maybe the one you linked.